# Social Sound Design Meetup?

Tags: ssd, social-sound-design, meet-up

I've been a member here for a little over a year and I've made some great friends so far.

I live and work in Los Angeles..

I'm sure a lot of other people who frequent this site do, too...

We can also meet halfway in Las Vegas...

And I might be going to the East Coast soon.. Florida for sure, at least.

Or we could all buy plane tickets to New Zealand and surprise Tim. heh. And from there, ya'all can hop in my G6 and we can fly over to South Africa and see Andrew.

But, I was also thinking, the studio I work at has about 25 Mac laptops. I could set them up all in a circle in my studio and skype everyone and we can see/talk to each other. Hah! (joke)

Anyone thought of a meet up before? Would be nice to meet some of you.

Comment: I was fortunate enough to meet some of the guys during my stay in New York :)

Answer (score 5):

I vote for a meetup scheduled around a tower implosion in Vegas. Then afterwards, we all share the files.

Answer (score 2):

Im in mexico, difficult time over here, if i flew to la or nz it would be to live there illegally haha, nice idea by the way

Answer (score 2):

Adding onto Jay's idea, what if we meet up around a big sound event like a tower implosion or stadium collapse, and then turn it into the source for a live Sound Design Challenge!

Or do another scavenger hunt one like this past month's.  It could be fun to have all of us running around some city with our gear!  Maybe break out into teams too?  Just some fun activity ideas for the meetup itself :)

Answer (score 2):

An L.A. meetup would be great, I'm game...latte, hike, would be nice to get out of our caves-:).

Answer (score 1):

I live in Salt Lake City, and my budget is pretty limited, but I could probably swing Las Vegas.

If we plan it around a convention, it gives people traveling farther the incentive, but it also means hotels may be more expensive.

Comment: Good idea and agreed. When is the next large shin-dig? AES?

Comment: AES, then Winter NAMM (I believe)...

Answer (score 1):

I've not been able to go to the first two but we have this in the UK.
http://sonicmeet.co.uk

Comment: I went to the second one, it was pretty good man! You should try and get down to the next one! 

Comment: Wasn't in the country for the first one and my wife was ill on the second one. Determined to get to the third! Isn't there one planned for September?

Answer (score 1):

I happy to meet up with anyone if there close to one of the most isolated metro cities on earth... 'Perth, WA, Australia'... It appears to be incredibly far from everything... :( But great for environmental sounds! :)

Comment: ooo... that's not too far off, just on the other side of the island! Hahaha... I'm over in Melbourne

Comment: i'll jump on the 4 o'clock 'Indian Pacific', should be there in 3 days! hehe

Comment: @Tak I'll be heading to Melbourne for a short visit in too long. btw have you done any work with Rising Phoenix Ent.?

Comment: Nah ive not done any work with those guys but I hear that there good, I do work mainly for West TV and working with students on films..


Answer (score 1):

Well....nice idea indeed.....but Germany seems to be too far away=)

Answer (score 1):

I believe there's a group trying to get started over on the sound_design [yahoo group](http://groups.yahoo.com/group/sound_design/message/24891) as well. I bet if you joined forces you could get a decent turn out.

I'll be in LA starting Jan 2012 and would love a chance to put some faces to names. In the meantime, @MixingManiac will be out there starting in Sept and I am positive she'd be down for a meetup too.

**EDIT:**

Just wanted to give this post a nudge. I'm in LA now and it would be awesome to put some faces and names to the handles. After the unfortunate passing of Seann Flynn in early December, I don't know if the LA Sound Group will continue or not. I do hope that it does. It sounded like a great crew of peers that I was really looking forward to be a part of.

Comment: I met your wife at the LA Sound Group I went to.

Comment: So I was told @Utopia. That's part of the reason I was looking forward to more of them. Although I do like @KathieT's idea of being out of our caves and in the wild.

Answer (score 1):

the dallas area guys are meeting up tomorrow

http://www.meetup.com/dallassounddesigners/

Answer (score 1):

Count me in for an LA area gathering.

Answer (score 1):

Great idea. I'd be down to meet up.